# Scala error when providing subclass instance in place of superclass?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am just trying things out in scala and I wrote this code

```
object Main:
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    val dInt: Data[Int] = IntData(1)
    val dString: Data[String] = StringData("hello")
    val Data(deconstructedInt) = dInt // unapply
    val Data(deconstructedString) = dString // unapply
    println(deconstructedInt)
    println(deconstructedString)


sealed trait Data[+T]:
  def get: T

case class IntData(get: Int) extends Data[Int]

case class StringData(get: String) extends Data[String]

object Data:
  def apply[T](input: T): Data[T] = input match {
    case i: Int => IntData(i) //compile error here
    case s: String => StringData(s) //compile error here
  }

  def unapply[T](d: Data[T]): Option[String] = d match {
    case IntData(get) => Some(s"int data => get = $get")
    case StringData(get) => Some(s"string data => get = $get")
  }
```

I get at the location commented in the code this error

```
Found:    IntData
Required: Data[T]
    case i: Int => IntData(i)
```

why I am getting this error, isn't `IntData` (or `StringData`) a subclass of `Data` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntData` is a subtype of `Data[Int]`. So if `T` is not `Int`, `IntData` is *not* a subtype of `Data[T]`. Now, you might say, if `input` matches the first case, then clearly `T` is `Int`. But the compiler is not smart to realise this!

You could try using Scala 3's new match types:

```
type DataOf[T] = T match {
  case Int => IntData
  case String => StringData
}

def apply[T](input: T): DataOf[T] = input match {
  case i: Int => IntData(i)
  case s: String => StringData(s)
}
```

Another alternative is union types:

```
def apply(input: Int | String): Data[Int | String] = input match {
  case i: Int => IntData(i)
  case s: String => StringData(s)
}
```

However, you will lose type information in doing this. Using the match types solution, `apply(42)` is inferred to have type `IntData`. Using the union types solution, it is inferred to have type `Data[Int | String]`.

Comment: and `DataOf[T]` is a `Data[T]` ? (the compiler is smart to know it in this case? I mean it knows it should do a widening of the `IntData` and `StringData` ?)

Comment: `DataOf[String]` is a `Data[String]`, and `DataOf[Int]` is a `Data[Int]`. However, if `x: T` and `T` is _unknown_, the compiler won't know what to do with `apply(x)`. You'd again require explicit pattern matching. Another alternative is to use union types. I'll extend my answer to mention those.

Answer (score 2):

This way compiler connects the dots between `T`s and it works:

```scala
  object Main:
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
      val dInt: Data[Int] = IntData(1)
      val dString: Data[String] = StringData("hello")
      val Data(deconstructedInt) = dInt // unapply
      val Data(deconstructedString) = dString // unapply
      println(deconstructedInt)
      println(deconstructedString)

  sealed trait Data[+T]:
    def get: T

  case class IntData[T <: Int](get: T) extends Data[T]

  case class StringData[T <: String](get: T) extends Data[T]

  object Data:
    def apply[T](input: T): Data[T] = input match {
      case i: Int    => IntData(i)
      case s: String => StringData(s)
    }

    def unapply[T](d: Data[T]): Option[String] = d match {
      case IntData(get)    => Some(s"int data => get = $get")
      case StringData(get) => Some(s"string data => get = $get")
    }
```